# Is there a better way to check for attribute in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a view you will throw an error if you say something like this when a review **without** a comment has been submitted:

```
<% if review.comment.title %>
```

Is there an easier way to check than nesting this line inside of `<% if review.comment %>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `review.comment.try(:title)`. It will return `nil`, if `review.comment` is `nil`.

Comment: Thanks. Just got back.. it's only been a few minutes :)  Happy to accept

Comment: By the way, I've never seen 4 upvotes on an answer in the first 20 minutes. Obviously a consensus!